# is it possible to upgrade a distro (debian) in an Encrypted LVM partition?

Tags: debian, partition, encryption, disk-encryption, dist-upgrade

I installed Debian on a VM using **Guided** Partitioning with **Encryption** and using **LVM** and it created something like this:

```
- /boot
- encrypted partition
-- LVM
--- /
--- /home
--- swap
```

After the successful installation, I tried to install Debian again, just to see how it's going to look like when I'm actually going to do a real system update on an encrypted partition. To my surprise, all I saw on manual partitioning was this:

```
- /boot
- a partition
```

My plan was to replace and format root partition and use /home partition without formatting.

Is it not possible to system upgrade when using encryption?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is correct. The installer is showing you the partitions, but your root and home filesystems are in LVM logical volumes (not partitions), which in turn is inside a LUKS container. You need to unlock the encrypted LUKS container/partition so that the logical volumes become accessible.

Comment: how should i unlock it?

Comment: Assuming the LUKS container is on sda2, then something like this: `cryptsetup open /dev/sda2 somename --type luks` You'll then need to enter the passphrase.

Comment: sorry for newbie questions, and where do i have to enter this cmd? i don't see any shell in Debian graphical installation.